# Show TwentyEleven header image only on home page

Tags: pages, headers

i am trying to remove the header from one page (actually all the pages exept the Home page)
i did some research i found this code #post-xx .entry-title{display:none;}
whereas the xx is the page ID . but it doesn t work for me
 do you know the exact code and exact place (and what s the page ID), or any other way...
any help would be appreciated

my website  www.danielbelseamusic.com

thanks a lot,daniel

Comment: can you explain what you mean exactly with 'header'? i guess you mean the title of the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the header image of the Twenty Eleven theme on other pages then your homepage, change the following code in header.php (in wp-content/themes/twentyeleven)

**Before:**

```
    <?php
        // Check to see if the header image has been removed
        $header_image = get_header_image();
        if ( ! empty( $header_image ) ) :
    ?>
```

**After:**

```
    <?php
        // Check to see if the header image has been removed
        $header_image = get_header_image();
        if ( ! empty( $header_image ) && is_front_page() ) :
    ?>
```

Comment: hi ptriek . there is my title danielbelseamusic , and there is a picture ( i call it the header picture) . i don t want this picture , it takes too much place , but the title is fine . also ,in which .php should i make changes (if is-stuffs)?

Comment: i updated my answer

Comment: thanks ptriek ,i have to check that out, and thank you all of you guys , you are surely very nice .

Comment: i just noticed my first code block was showing the wrong code, i updated this...

Comment: i am sorry ptriek . i don t understand . i don t see all that in the .php header . are you telling me to add on my .php header that :<?php         // Check to see if the header image has been removed         $header_image = get_header_image();         if ( ! empty( $header_image ) && is_front_page() ) :     ?>      i am quite confused .merci bien:)

Comment: 1. Open wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/header.php 2. Go to line 81  `if ( ! empty( $header_image ) ) :` 3. Replace this line with this code: `if ( ! empty( $header_image ) && is_front_page() ) :`

Comment: woooow it works :) thank u so much ptriek , thank u all   i actually did it with your previous comment (before, after...)i didn t get it at the beginning (i am a beginner in all that)but now it works .i didn t do it with wp-content ,because i don t know where is the wp-content .thanx again

Comment: i put yes to was this post useful.is it what u meant?

Comment: no you have to click on the 'V' icon below the 0 (top left of the answer) - that way the question will be marked as 'answered'.

Comment: do u think is it ok now

Comment: no see [this](http://www.thebackoffice.be/tmp/accept.png) --> you have to click on the check mark (and on the up arrow if you think it is a good answer)

Comment: i think it s all right now for the check mark (correct?), but for the up i receive a message that i need more reputation or something like that .

Comment: jeej, you did it :-)  yeah, forgot about the reputation...

Answer (score 0):

In your comment to Viruthagiri, you mention that "the picture takes too much place", so, assuming you actually want to remove an *image* in the header, and not the *header* itself, you could do something quick like this :

```
 <?php if( is_home() ) { ?>
      <img src="your-image-source-here" />
 <?php } ?>
```

Inside your header.php file

Comment: hi Shane . but i want the image on my home page . i just don t want it in the other pages

Comment: that if statement checks if it is home and prints the image. It will not display on other pages