# Replace header with large image on home page only, using Genesis child theme

Tags: php, css, genesis-theme-framework, header-image

Having looked at [Show TwentyEleven header image only on home page](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/36570/show-twentyeleven-header-image-only-on-home-page), [Replace Home with image link inside custom header menu](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/331138/replace-home-with-image-link-inside-custom-header-menu) and more, I don't see what I am trying to do.

**We want to replace the header only on the home page, with a much taller image.** FYI I am not the designer and we had an intern using a lot of plugins to modify sidebars and build pages, so that's not me LOL. I prefer code-based solutions, not plugins.

**QUESTION IS:** I have this code in the Genesis child theme (Outreach Pro, also beyond my control) front-page.php:

```
/**  added by jim 6/28/19 per https://wpsites.net/web-design/remove-header/
     remove header on front page (this file) from   */
remove_action( 'genesis_header', 'genesis_header_markup_open', 5 );
remove_action( 'genesis_header', 'genesis_do_header' );
remove_action( 'genesis_header', 'genesis_header_markup_close', 15 );
```

This successfully suppressed the header, but now it seems like I can't use after_header type code to place my image. Instead I am trying to use a `::before` on the nav menu in css like this:

```
/** jim's customizations July 2019 for tall Bob Gray image replacing header on home page only */
.nav-primary:before {
 content:url(/images/robert-c-gray-banner-maskbob-sharpen.jpg);
padding−right:6px;
}
```

But it's not showing up and the Inspector doesn't show it either.

Is the `::before` on the `nav-primary` selector a good approach? ([I got the idea here](https://organicweb.com.au/wordpress/css-before-pseudo/).) FWIW I will need to float some text over this image as well.

Thanks for any guidance. Here's [the page I am working on (test page)](http://railroad.social/virginia5) and here's [what another page looks like with the header](http://train.team/schedule7). Any suggestions to improve the question are quite welcome!

Comment: I just set up the short links (using Blink) at the bottom of the question, they work for me, if not for you I'll post actual links

Comment: I see with the Genesis Visual Hook Guide plugin there is a genesis_before hook, I am gonna try that one instead of the CSS approach.

Answer (score 0):

Well I got it working with a different approach but a good answer that provides insight why the approach in my question didn't work will be accepted as the answer.

I put this in functions.php for the child theme:

```
add_action( 'genesis_before_header', 'bob_gray_image', 10 );

function bob_gray_image() {
    if ( is_front_page() ) {
        echo('<div class="bobgrayimage"><img src="/images/robert-c-gray-banner-maskbob-sharpen.jpg"></div>'); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's quite possible that your path url(/images/robert-c-gray-banner-maskbob-sharpen.jpg) is not correct.
Because you mentioned a backslash url("/"images/.....); You shouldn't use / at first of your url. Try this code, I am sure it will fix that.
url(images/robert-c-gray-banner-maskbob-sharpen.jpg)